# Random Color Generation on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, arc4random

I have the following code for generating a random color (Objective C):

```
- (UIColor*) randomColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0) green:
           (arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0) 
           blue:(arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0) alpha:1];
}
```

It's worked as intended in all of my simulations. However, now that it's been sent out to some testers, **it always generates black (0, 0, 0) for people with iPhone 5S's**. Doesn't occur for a friend with a 5C nor for a couple friends with 4S's. I have no idea how to pinpoint this error. Does anyone know why this could be?

Edit: one tester with an iPhone 6 confirmed the same problem, so I suppose the version isn't relevant. However, it is still working fine for others.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to generate a random number between 0 and 1 you should use `drand48()` instead of `arc4random_uniform()`

```
- (UIColor*) randomColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:drand48() green:drand48() blue:drand48() alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: Please OP could you reply how it went with this solution? I've set up a sample proyect and got 5 times the exact same greenish color (on the simulator).

Comment: I've used this change and resubmitted my app. On simulations, this way seems to work (but beforehand my code worked in simulations too). I'll reply in a few days if my app gets through and this code does the trick.

However, if you're getting a greenish (non-black) color, you might have a different problem than me.

Comment: Ok, please reply when the tests comeback so I know this works on real devices.

Comment: While using `drand48` may be a nice way to get a value between 0 and 1, there should be nothing wrong with the OP's code. Why would `arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0` give only 0 when on 64-bit devices?

Comment: Same problem. Still doesn't occur on simulations.